# How can I figure out when I started playing Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I would like to know the exact date when I started to play to Clash of Clans, but I can't find this information anywhere in the game. Where can I find it?

Comment: You'll want to hit support up with that. We don't have access to Supercell's databases.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to exactly know when you started playing Clash of Clans in the game itself. I think the closest you can get from the exact date would be to look when you unlocked your oldest achievement in the game, as some of them can be unlocked in the tutorial itself. I think you can look for one of these two:

- Bigger Coffers: Upgrade your Gold Storage to level 2.
- Nice and Tidy: Destroy 5 obstacles.

This will give you the year and month of the unlock and not the exact date, but there is no real way at the moment to get an exact date.

Answer (score 1):

Look at iTunes purchase history. 
Settings>[your name]>iTunes & App Store>tap Apple ID. Swipe up to purchase history. 
I found exact date. Feb 25th 2013 app was installed.